# Comparing two arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I have two arrays for a project that mimics a student multiple choice test. The first array is the 20 correct answers to the test:

(correct answers) correct[] has these numbers in it:

```
  1,4,3,3,2,2,1,1,4,5,3,3,3,5,2,4,2,5,4,5
```

(student's answers) answers[] has these numbers in it:

```
  0,3,3,0,2,4,0,1,4,5,0,3,3,1,2,4,2,0,4,5
```

If the student selects "0" they are admitting they don't know the answer and their score remains the same. If they select a wrong answer they lose 0.25 marks and if they select the answer they receive 1 mark.

I'm trying to figure out how to create a loop that compares the elements in each array and gives the student an overall grade.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Edit: This is the code I tried:

```
double totalGrade = 0;

while(i <= 20) {

    switch(studentAnswer){

    case 0:
        break;
    case 1:
        if(correct[i] == answers[i])
        {
            totalGrade ++;
        }
        else {
            totalGrade = totalGrade - 0.25;
        }
    case2:
        if(correct[i] == answers[i])                    
        {
            totalGrade ++;
        } 
        else {
            totalGrade = totalGrade - 0.25;
        }
    case 3:
        if(correct[i] == answers[i])                    
        {
            totalGrade ++;
        }else {
            totalGrade = totalGrade - 0.25;
        } 
    case 4:
        if(correct[i] == answers[i])                    
        {
            totalGrade ++;
        }  
        else {
            totalGrade = totalGrade - 0.25;
        }
    case 5:
        if(correct[i] == answers[i])                    
        {
            totalGrade ++;
        }else {
            totalGrade = totalGrade - 0.25;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Use a for loop that goes from 0 to the length of the answer array, then index both arrays to get the current elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(int i=0; i<correct.length; i++){
    if(answers[i] == correct[i]){
        totalGrade += 1;
    } else if(answers[i]!=0){
        totalGrade -= 0.25;
    }
}
```

Edit: That's not really the proper use for a switch/case statement since most cases do the exact same thing. If you wanted to go that route, it would be more like

```
for(int i=0; i<correct.length; i++){
    switch(answers[i]){
        case 0:
            break;
        case else:
            if(answers[i] == correct[i]){
                totalGrade += 1;
            } else{
                totalGrade -= 0.25;
            }
            break;
    }
}
```